# c# url action with multiple parameter one is null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

I have a jquery $.getJson call to a controller action that returns a json.

The action accepts 3 parameters:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> MyAction(string id, string name, string age)
{
    .... code here     
}
```

and in JavaScript

```
$.getJson('@Url.Action("MyAction", "MyController", new { @id= Model.Id, @name=Model.Name, @age=Model.Age })')
```

The problem is that in the action only the Id and Name values are provided the `age is null`. The age value is ther. If I just display the age on the page

@Model.Age

the values is shown ... somehow is not set to the action.

The route looks like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Basically only the first 2 parameters are sent to action. The third one is null. I have a feeling is a route issues here, but cannot figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually solved this by adding a new route to my RouteConfig.cs class:

Now it looks like this. Notice the new name and age parameters:

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");


        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "UserRoute",
            url: "{
                     controller}/{action}/{id}/{name}/{age}",
                     defaults: new { 
                                    controller = "Home", 
                                    action = "Index", 
                                    id = UrlParameter.Optional, 
                                    name = UrlParameter.Optional, 
                                    age = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { 
                             controller = "Home", 
                             action = "Index", 
                             id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are sending a JSON object to the controller, why not send 3 parameters?  Otherwise your controller action really needs something like this to match your request:

```
public class DataClass{
   public string id;
   public string name;
   public string age;
}
```

Change your controller:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> MyAction(DataClass data)
{
   .... code here     
}
```

Comment: then it's getting set as null

Comment: why don't you show your js Model class?  Also place a `debugger;` line before you send the data to verify.

Comment: There is actually no data that is sent but just a get issues to that url with the parameters. The @Url.Action helper formats the url but the parameters are received from the model. Actually I checked it with Fiddler and the request (url) is formatted properly. The problem is in the MVC side.

Comment: Here is the url from fiddler: `https://localhost:44314/MyController/MyAction/2f9d59d1-92ae-4028-b3d7-e08c2ebf0123?name=Jhon&amp;age=23&_=1437254972485 `

Comment: As you can see all parameters are there: id, name and age. on the mvc side age  only is null

Comment: Age is actually lower, no problem with that was just a mistake from my side. The id is the actual guid after the action, as you can see the route is controller/action/id

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83636/discussion-between-user2818430-and-t-mckeown).

Comment: your not sending json...  change your code to send as a real object.  `new { id: \"@Model.Id\", name: \"@Model.name\", age: \"@Model.age\" }`

Comment: I'm assuming the `@Model.Id` is your razor code in the js section.

Comment: I actually solved this. The problem was in the route. So basically I don't need to post an object but just issue a get request to the url. The MVC was not understanding the parameters so I had to add a route for that.